# How to set timeout on client socket connection?

Tags: java, sockets

I am trying to set the timeout of a connection on the client socket in Java. I have set the *connection timeout* to 2000 milliseconds, i.e:

```
this.socket.connect(this.socketAdd, timeOut);
```

This I am trying on a web application. When a user makes a request, I am passing values to socket server, but if I don't receive any response in 5 secs the socket should disconnect.

But in my case the whole request is getting submitted once again. Can any one please tell me where am I going wrong?

I want to cut the socket connection, if I don't get any response in 5 secs. How can I set it? Any sample code would help.

Answer (score 63):

You can try the follwoing:

```
Socket client = new Socket();   
client.connect(new InetSocketAddress(hostip, port_num), connection_time_out);
```

Comment: This helped me for a timeout when the server doesn't exist, or is refusing connection.

Comment: btw, `connection_time_out` is in milliseconds

Answer (score 38):

To put the whole thing together:

```
Socket socket = new Socket();
// This limits the time allowed to establish a connection in the case
// that the connection is refused or server doesn't exist.
socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host, port), timeout);
// This stops the request from dragging on after connection succeeds.
socket.setSoTimeout(timeout);
```

Comment: Shouldn't the SoTimeout be set before you enter the blocking operation ?

Answer (score 20):

What you show is a timeout for the connection, this will timeout if it cannot connect within a certain time.

Your question implies you want a timeout for when you are already connected and send a request, you want to timeout if there is no response within a certain amount of time.

Presuming you mean the latter, then you need to timeout the `socket.read()` which can be done by setting `SO_TIMEOUT` with the [Socket.setSoTimeout(int timeout)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#setSoTimeout%28int%29) method. This will throw an exception if the read takes longer than the number of milliseconds specified.  For example:

```
this.socket.setSoTimeout(timeOut);
```

An alternative method is to do the read in a thread, and then wait on the thread with a timeout and close the socket if it timesout.

Comment: Does "soTimeout" consider TCP acks? Let's say I send some data at time 't' and receive an acknowledgement from server at time 't' + 10. Nothing is received from the server after this ack. If "soTimeout" was set to 20 on my client , then will TCP layer consider the connection as closed at 't'+20 or at 't'+30.

Comment: In case TCP will consider the connection closed at 't'+20 then yes setting "soTimeout" is same as reading on separate thread and timing out the thread otherwise it's not. This distinction is important as in case of TCP keep-alive acks are sent by server periodically to keep the connection alive. read from socket will never return because of keep-alive ack packets and so a tcp connection might break despite connection being active with server.