# How to tell if the server socket is not available?

Tags: java, android, sockets

socket client is running on android:

```
try {
    socketClient = new Socket(host, port);

    //set socket input
    in = socketClient.getInputStream();
    dIn = new DataInputStream(in);

    //set socket output
    out = socketClient.getOutputStream();
    dOut = new DataOutputStream(out);

    int c = 0;
    String data = "";

    while ((c = dIn.read()) != -1) {
       //print data
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    //close connection
}
```

my server run on python and everything is works fine except until the server is not running and when i try to connect to server it takes  two minutes to catch the error that the server is not available 
How can I reduce the time for example catch the error in 10 sec

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9029329

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9029329)

use

```
Socket socketClient = new Socket();   
socketClient.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host, port),connection_time_out)
```

instead of

```
socketClient = new Socket(host, port);
```

connection_time_out = limits the time allowed to establish a connection in the case that the connection is refused or server doesn't exist.