# Meaning of different timeouts in SSHJ

Tags: java, ssh, sftp, sshj

I am trying to use SSHJ to connect to a SFTP from my Java application.
There are a couple of different timeouts that are present but I can't find the difference between them. Even the official docs aren't very helpful.
Can someone explain the difference between?

```
SSHClient.setTimeout()
SSHClient.setConnectTimeout()
SFTPEngine.setTimeoutMs()
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

- `SSHClient.setTimeout()` – It is propagated to [`Socket.setSoTimeout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#setSoTimeout-int-) – See [What is the functionality of setSoTimeout and how it works?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12820874/850848)

- `SSHClient.setConnectTimeout()` – It is propagated to [`Socket.connect`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#connect-java.net.SocketAddress-int-) – See [How to set timeout on client socket connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5632279/850848)
- `SFTPEngine.setTimeoutMs()` – How long to wait for a response from the SFTP server. Basically, it seems to be an equivalent of `SSHClient.setTimeout()`, just on a different OSI level.